# Unexpected Top-Level Exception in android-support-v4.jar

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, facebook-android-sdk, android-appcompat

I have a problem when I want to compile my app:

> UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added`

It seems to be a error with android-support-v4.jar.

In my project I have 3 libraries: appcompat, facebook, google_play_services.

My gradle files:

- AppProject/settings.gradle

  ```
  include ':libraries:google_play_services', ':libraries:appcompat', ':libraries:facebook', ':app'
  ```
- AppProject/build.gradle :

  ```
  buildscript {
      repositories {
          mavenCentral()
      }
      dependencies {
          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
      }
  }
  ```
- AppProject/app/build.gradle:

  ```
  apply plugin: 'android'

  dependencies {
      compile project(':libraries:appcompat')
      compile project(':libraries:facebook')
      compile project(':libraries:google_play_services')
      compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.3.jar')
      compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
      compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar')
      compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.8.4.jar')
      compile files('libs/urbanairship-lib-3.0.0.jar')
  }
  ```
- AppProject/libraries/appcompat/build.gradle:

  ```
  apply plugin: 'android-library'

  dependencies {
      compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
      compile files('libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar')
  }
  ```
- AppProject/libraries/facebook/buidle.gradle:

  ```
  apply plugin: 'android-library'

  dependencies {
      compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
  }
  ```
- AppProject/libraries/google_play_services/buidle.gradle:

  ```
  apply plugin: 'android-library'

  dependencies {
      compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
  }
  ```

But when I compile it, this error appears:

```
Output:
        UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompatIceCreamSandwich;
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the problem :

**AppProject/settings.gradle**

```
include ':libraries:facebook', ':app'
```

**AppProject/libraries/facebook/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
}
```

**AppProject/app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'

    compile project(':libraries:facebook')
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.8.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/urbanairship-lib-3.0.0.jar')
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate on what the problem was? And how did you solve this issue ?

Answer (score 6):

The main idea in Prcaen's answer is that using:

`compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'`

inside **dependency** section instead of:

`compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')`

can solve the duplication problem.
And it does!

Answer (score 2):

You probably have that jar file included twice in your project. Try going to File -> Project Structure and checking if you have 2 identical modules or libraries.

Answer (score 2):

As I see from your build files you have added android-support library to two of your modules. I had the exact same problem and solved it by removing the library from the main module, leaving only the one for the library one. I'm not sure that this is the best solution but it works and gradle doesn't complain.